# How I can get definite value in keyvalue pair?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

My object has a specific set of key / value pairs,
i want to get a specific value, not everything, how can i do this?

For example:

.ts

```
movie = {
     title:'title',
     description:'descriprtion',
     rating:4

    };
```

html:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of movie | keyvalue">
    <li> {{item.value}} </li>
</ul>
```

And I only want to receive item.description, can you tell me how this can be implemented?

Comment: you can simple use `{{item.description}}` and forget the *ngFor,  or use a *ngIf `<li *ngIf="item.key=='description'">{{item.value}}</li>` see the docs about [text interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <ul *ngFor="let item of movie | keyvalue">
      <ng-container *ngIf="item.key === 'description'">
        <li>{{item.value}}</li>
      </ng-container>
    </ul>
```

But to be honest you would be better off just doing:

```
    <div>{{ move.description }}</div>
```

Since you do not seem to want to iterate the object props, but only want description.

Comment: Tried to do a better one, but it gave me an empty list